# In Tableau, how do you modify the default setting for number of decimals of a percentage?

Tags: tableau-api

It's currently set to 2 decimal places, I'd like it to default to 0. Can we configure this?

While it's a small efficieny gain, but I'd like to be able to have this set to 0 decimal places as the default.
Note, I am not looking for how to set a measure's default properties, but instead that whenever any measure is set to percentage that the default can be set by the baseline default.
For example, if I do a quick table calculation of a measure such as SUM(Sales) as 'percentage of Total', I'd like the default to be 0 decimal places, not 2 as is the current setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau Desktop and Tableau Server both do not support this feature.  [There is an idea for this on the Tableau Ideas site](https://community.tableau.com/s/idea/0874T000000HBtKQAW/detail) which you can vote for to try to get the feature added to the product.